# How to prompt user to turn on Location Services using adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, gps, geolocation, adobe

I am developing an app that uses GPS, so typically the app must prompt the user to turn Gps on if it is muted.
So is there a way to open the Location Services menu from inside my app using adobe air?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine an ANE would be required for this.

Perhaps contact Distriqt to see if they would consider adding the functionality to one of their existing ANE's ?

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.NetworkInfo